# Background color of selected item on a ListView is not change?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I try to do this with `setMultiChoiceModeListener` but is not working. When i select the multiple item of listview its not highlight that item. I do many things but its not working.See my code is given bellow.

Listview in xml file.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_ChatMsg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll_msg"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:divider="@color/main_background"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stackFromBottom="true" />
```

This is my `MessageAdapter.java` for message adapter.

```
private SparseBooleanArray SelectedItemsId;
public ArrayList<MessageList> arr_Message;

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selectView(position, !SelectedItemsId.get(position));
}

private void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("remove", "position--  " + position + "value-- " + value);
    if (value) {
        SelectedItemsId.put(position, value);
        // rl_MsgItem.setBackgroundResource(R.color.outofstoke);
    } else {
        SelectedItemsId.delete(position);
        // rl_MsgItem.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public int getSelectedCount() {
    Log.e("getSelectedCount",
            "getSelectedCount----  " + SelectedItemsId.size());
    return SelectedItemsId.size();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    Log.e("SparseBooleanArray", "SparseBooleanArray");
    return SelectedItemsId;
}

public void remove(MessageList messageList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("remove", "remove");
    arr_Message.remove(messageList);
    removeSelection();
}

public void removeSelection() {
    Log.e("removeSelection", "removeSelection");
    SelectedItemsId = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And my code in `MessageActivit.java` is bellow.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
        // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
        SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();

        // Captures all selected ids with a loop
        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                MessageList selecteditem = (MessageList) adapter
                        .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));

                // Remove selected items following the ids
                arr_Message.remove(selecteditem);
            }
        }
        mode.finish();
        adapter = new MessageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arr_Message);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
        long id, boolean checked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (checked == true) {
        Log.e("Position", "" + position);
    } else {
        Log.e("Position", "" + position);
    }
    final int checkedCount = lv_ChatMsg.getCheckedItemCount();
    mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected Message");
    adapter.toggleSelection(position);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this in your item xml file .

```
<Linerlayout 
    ...
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    ... >
    other your item code.
 </Linerlayout>
```